# How to tell if navigator.permissions.query with a certain permission is supported

Tags: javascript, firefox, permissions, cross-browser, navigator

I have the following code:

```
if (navigator.permissions && navigator.permissions.query) {
  navigator.permissions.query({
    name: 'clipboard-write'
  }).then(function(result) {
    if (result.state === 'granted') {
      //Do something!
    } else{
      //Not granted...
    }
} else {
  //Does not support navigator.permissions
}
```

This works in Safari and Chrome.  In Firefox however, it throws this error:

```
TypeError: 'name' member of PermissionDescriptor 'clipboard-write' is not a valid value for enumeration PermissionName.
```

The `navigator.permissions.query` is supported, just not `clipboard-write`.  So, how do I see if the browser supports:

```
navigator.permissions.query({name:'clipboard-write'})
```

I have thought I could maybe just check what browser is being used, but I think there has to be a better way of doing it.

**EDIT ( try / catch )**

I tried `try/catch` with the following code:

```
try {
  navigator.permissions.query({
    name:'clipboard-write'
  });
}
catch(error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Unfortunately this does not `catch` in Firefox.

Comment: You could use `try/catch`

Comment: @Barmar I tried that, am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but seeing that you didn't get any answer, and in case anyone stumbles upon this question:

`navigator.permissions` returns a Promise, so in addition to `.then()` you can use `.catch()` for when the Promise is rejected.

`clipboard-write` seems to be availabie in Firefox now, so I used `camera` in this example, which will still fail in Firefox (any nonsensical value would do as well in order to test this).

```js
navigator.permissions.query({
    name: 'camera'
  })
  .then((permissionObj) => {
    console.log(permissionObj);
    // ... check the permission object ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // couldn't query the permission
    console.error(error);
  });
```